# How to setup the root for Tests in Python in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, configuration

```
project\
  src\
      __init__.py  
  tests\
      __init__.py
      stubs\r_json_response_expired.json
```

Within my test I have to load a JSON file. this.

```
@patch('requests.post')
def test_subscription_delete_only_if_invalid(self, mock_post):
    with app.app_context():
        expires_at = datetime.utcnow()
        m = self.inject_expired_r_json()

def inject_expired_r_json(self):
        with open('stubs/r_json_response_expired.json') as fb_file:
            receipt_response = json.load(fb_file)
        m = MagicMock()
        m.json = MagicMock(name='json')
        m.json.return_value = receipt_response
        return m
```

When running the test VS Code shows:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>   'stubs/r_json_response_expired.json'

I have `.env` in my project:

PYTHONPATH=./src

And in settings.json (VS CODE)

```
"terminal.integrated.env.osx": {
    "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}/src"
},
"python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env"
```

I don't like changing the path in the test to avoid breaking PyCharm, if I happen to switch the IDE.

Comment: run `pip install -e .` to install your project in development mode in your virtualenv, then use `DIRNAME = os.path.dirname(__file__)` at a central location and hang all your paths off this.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the current directory while your tests are running is your workspace root, `project`. Probably your best option is to use [`importlib_resources`](https://pypi.org/project/importlib-resources/) to read the file. If you place a `__init__.py` file in stubs you can then read the JSON file as:

```py
import importlib_resources

from . import stubs

data = importlib_resources.files(stubs).joinpath('r_json_response_expired.json').read_text()
```

If for some reason you can't put an `__init__.py` in the directory then you can create the file path using pathlib.

```py
import pathlib

data_path = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent / "stubs" / "r_json_response_expired.json"
data = data_path.read_text(encoding="utf-8")
```